# Square integrability of the harmonic extension in the upper half-plane

Tags: real-analysis, integration, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

Let $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$, and consider its harmonic extension in the upper half-plane given by $u(x,y) = (P(\cdot,y) * f)(x)$, where
$$P(x,y) = C \frac{y}{(\lvert x \rvert^2 + y^2)^{\frac{n+1}{2}}}$$
is the Poisson kernel. My problem is to prove (or disprove) that
$u \in L^2(\mathbb{R^n} \times (0, \infty))$.

The motivation comes from [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.05159) paper,
where in Theorem 9 the above problem is part of a more general argument.
However, there is no proof in the paper.

My strategy was to split the integral
$\lVert u \rVert_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n \times (0,\infty))}^2$
into two parts for $0<y<1$ and $1<y<\infty$ and find appropriate estimates,
but I've had no success in estimating the $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$-norm of $u$ when $y > 1$.
Intuitively it seems clear that the $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$-norm diminishes as $y \to \infty$
but by what rate?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say $u_y(t)=u(t+iy)$. If you look at the Fourier transform of $P(.,y)$ you see that $$\widehat u_y(\xi)=e^{-y|\xi|}\widehat f(\xi).$$

Hence $$||u_y||_2^2=\int e^{-2y|\xi|}|\widehat f(\xi)|^2\,d\xi,$$so
$$\int_0^\infty||u_y||_2^2\,dy=\int\frac1{2|\xi|}|\widehat f(\xi)|^2\,d\xi;$$
so $u\in L^2$ if and only if that last integral is finite.

(This even makes sense. The reason $||u_y||_2$ should tend to zero is cancellation in the integral; saying $\widehat f(0)=0$ says $\int f=0$, cancellation.)

Comment: Thank you, that makes perfect sense! However, now I don't see how the result in the cited paper is true. In the paper, $f$ is assumed to belong to the fractional Sobolev space $H^s$, where now $s=1/2$, but I don't think that the last integral in your answer is finite for such functions.

Comment: i wouldn't know about the proof in that paper. seems to me the final condition above says that $f\in H^{-1/2}$, not $H^{1/2}$.